I am creating a class project the code seems fine however when i rebuilt it crash
this below is the error I get when rebuild
@Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type
public abstract android.content.res.loader.AssetsProvider  localAssetsProvider(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

//and this also is showing
@Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type
//problem seems to come from these tree code
//the class assets provider implementation
class AssetsProviderImpl @Inject constructor(
@ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
): AssetsProvider {
override suspend fun getJsonData(fileName: String)  =
    context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use{
    it.readText()
}
@SuppressLint("DiscourageApi")

override suspend fun getDrawableResourceId(name: String) =
    context.resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.packageName)



}
//the interface that I created
interface AssetsProvider {

suspend fun getJsonData(fileName: String): String
suspend fun getDrawableResourceId(name: String): Int

}

//the AppProviderModule is where I think the error is 
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class AppProviderModule {

@Binds
@Singleton

abstract fun localAssetsProvider(impl: AssetsProviderImpl): AssetsProvider

@Binds
@Singleton
abstract fun boroughsRepositoryProvider(impl: BoroughsRepositoryImpl):   BoroughsRepository
}

